# Apache Rewrite Rules for SEO URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to use Apache mod_rewrite to have SEO URLS I have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?a=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The first part which is redirect to www and https works fine but I need to achieve the following URL rewrites which is not working:

1. `https://www.domain.com/index.php?a=explore` to `https://www.domain.com/explore/`
2. `https://www.domain.com/index.php?a=page&b=about` to `https://www.domain.com/about/`
3. `https://www.domain.com/index.php?a=track&id=9` to `https://www.domain.com/track/idno`
4. `https://www.domain.com/index.php?a=explore&filter=newtag` to `https://www.domain.com/explore/newtag/`

Comment: If URL is `https://www.domain.com/foo/bar` then how do you want to be rewritten?

Comment: Sorry forgot a to between the links fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rule should work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php?a=(explore)(?:&filter=([^\s&]+))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php?a=(track)&id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/%2/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php?a=page&b=about [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /about/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(explore)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?a=$1&filter=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(track)/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?a=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(about)/?$ /index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, This works for me however I am facing another issue with the scrip as the script does not use the rewrite version of URLs by default when I browse the website it uses the original urls but accessing the rewritten urls directly works fine. I am using http://phpsound.com/demo/ . Do I need to somehow add code and tell the scrip use rewritten urls instead of original ?